# Object created from the class "object" does not allow to retrieve property values

Tags: c#, object, reflection, propertyinfo

I have an object created from the class "object" and it contains a list I have created. The list is a collection of objects created from a class called "MyClass". And, that class contains two string properties.

```
public Class MyClass 
{
    private string _propOne;
    public string PropOne
    {
       get {return _propOne;}
       set {_propOne=Value;}
    }

    private string _propTwo;
    public string PropTwo
    {
       get {return _propTwo;}
       set {_propTwo=Value;}
    }
}
```

I have a method which returns an object of the class "object"

```
private object GetData() 
{
    // It converts the list created to an object created from the class "object"
}
```

Then I call the method like in the following.

```
object temp=GetData();
```

Now I want to iterate over "temp" and assign it to another list created from the objects of the class "MyClass".

```
private List<MyClass> _anotherCollection;
public List<MyClass> AnotherCollection
{
   get {return _anotherCollection;}
   set {_anotherCollection=Value;}
}

........................

foreach (var a in temp.GetType().GetProperties())
{
   object firstParam = "PropOne";
   object secondParam = "PropTwo";
   AnotherCollection.Add(new MyClass() { PropOne = a.GetValue(firstParam), PropTwo = a.GetValue(PropTwo) });
}
```

But it gives me the following compilation error.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Can someone help me to fix it ?

Comment: `GetValue` expects string as parameter, you are passing an `object`. Change `object firstParam = ` to `string firstParam`, and the same for `secondParam`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast the returned object from `GetValue` to a `string`. The compiler doesn't know that the `object` returned from `GetValue` is actually a `string`, so you have to tell it that like this.

Also, you have to pass in the instance you are trying to get the value for (`temp` in this case):

```
PropOne = (string)a.GetValue(temp)
```

Comment: Now there is an exception saying "Object does not match target type"

Comment: Did you use `temp` also for the second call?

Comment: No. The only place I use "temp" is in the foreach loop. That's the only place

Comment: I did. It doesn't work either.  there is no error. But what the collection contains is some numbers and that is not what I want.              Data.Add(new MyClass() { PropOne = (a.GetValue(temp)).ToString(), PropTwo = (a.GetValue(temp)).ToString() });

Comment: So what are the properties (`a`) you retrieved?

Comment: In the collection it contains, some numbers, like :